# KeyError: 20908 when tyring to fine-tune bert model

Tags: bert-language-model, training-data, keyerror

I'm trying to do fine-tune bert model with custom dataset . and this error occured while training model. i have no idea why this error occured please help

---

```
class DataLoader(Dataset):
    """
    Custom Dataset class for handling tokenized text data and corresponding labels.
    Inherits from torch.utils.data.Dataset.
    """
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        """
        Initializes the DataLoader class with encodings and labels.

        Args:
            encodings (dict): A dictionary containing tokenized input text data
                              (e.g., 'input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask').
            labels (list): A list of integer labels for the input text data.
        """
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """
        Returns a dictionary containing tokenized data and the corresponding label for a given index.

        Args:
            idx (int): The index of the data item to retrieve.

        Returns:
            item (dict): A dictionary containing the tokenized data and the corresponding label.
        """
        # Retrieve tokenized data for the given index
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        # Add the label for the given index to the item dictionary
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Returns the number of data items in the dataset.

        Returns:
            (int): The number of data items in the dataset.
        """
        return len(self.labels)
```

---

```
trainer = Trainer(
    # the pre-trained model that will be fine-tuned 
    model=model,
     # training arguments that we defined above                        
    args=training_args,                 
    train_dataset=train_dataloader,         
    #eval_dataset=val_dataloader,  
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,          
    compute_metrics= compute_metrics
)
```

---

```
trainer.train()
```

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\tngus\anaconda3\envs\bert_test\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3653, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
3652 try:
-> 3653     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3654 except KeyError as err:

File c:\Users\tngus\anaconda3\envs\bert_test\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\index.pyx:147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File c:\Users\tngus\anaconda3\envs\bert_test\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\index.pyx:176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2606, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2630, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 20908

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\tngus\Desktop\bigleader_koTra_project_share\code\HSH_testcode\Multi-class_Classification.ipynb 셀 51 line 1
----> 1 trainer.train()

File c:\Users\tngus\anaconda3\envs\bert_test\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py:1553, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
1551         hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()
...
3658     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
3659     #  the TypeError.
3660     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 20908
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

fine-tune bert model